# Elasticsearch multiple field search endpoint

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have the following URL what executes a elasticsearch _search request with a filter on it.

```
https://mysupersite.local/apiman-gateway/tommie/ckanlastic/2.0?q=tags:“013”
```

I want to search for multiple values within this URL. So it must execute an AND query.

Something like this ( Not working)

```
https://mysupersite.local/apiman-gateway/tommie/ckanlastic/2.0?q=tags:“013”&theme:“bestuur”
```

Now it executes an OR request, so then i only search for theme:bestuur.

Is this possible within this URL request endpoint or do i need to set the header body?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [query string syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax), i.e. `tags:"013" AND theme:"bestuur"`. When URL-encoded, this gives the following URL

```
https://mysupersite.local/apiman-gateway/tommie/ckanlastic/2.0?q=tags:"013"+AND+theme:"bestuur"
```